# Form Shows and hides again: jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a form when a button is clicked. But it shows for a second or so and then hides again. i have tried to debug it with console.log() but my jQuery is not reaching in the anonymous function in click event in chrome console it is showing me this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" Here is my code

```
        <asp:Panel id="dynamicSubForm" class="container"  runat="server" DefaultButton="btnAdd" DefaultFocus="txtSegment">
            <div class="subForm">
                <div id="subHeader" class="divRow">
                    <div class="headCol">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                            Text="Sources"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="subFormRow">
                    <div>&nbsp</div>
                </div>
                <div class="subFormRow">
                    <div class="subFormFstCol">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server" Text="Source:"></asp:Label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="subFormScndCol">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSource" runat="server" 
                            CssClass="whiteCtrl" DataSourceID="dsIrrigationSource" 
                            DataTextField="title" DataValueField="id">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsIrrigationSource" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MIS4BOSConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [title] FROM [IrrigationSource]">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="subFormRow">
                    <div class="subFormFstCol">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblSegment" runat="server" Text="Area Segment:"></asp:Label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="subFormScndCol">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSegment" runat="server" CssClass="whiteCtrl"></asp:TextBox>
                        %<br />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revArea0" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtSegment" Display="Dynamic" 
                            ErrorMessage="Percentage must be all digits." ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="subFormRow">
                    <div class="subFormFstCol">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text="Description:"></asp:Label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="subFormScndCol">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server" Height="70px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                            CssClass="whiteCtrl"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="subFormRow">
                    <div class="subFormFstCol">

                    </div>
                    <div class="subFormScndCol">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="blueBtn" Text="Add" 
                            onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddCancel" runat="server" CssClass="whiteBtn" 
                            Text="Cancel" onclick="btnAddCancel_Click" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSubMsg" runat="server" CssClass="usrMsg" Text="Label" 
                            Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
enter code here
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var subForm = $("#MainContent_dynamicSubForm");
        var addBtn = $("#irrAdd");

        console.log("before hide");
        subForm.hide();
        console.log("after hide");
        addBtn.on("click", function () {
            console.log('in anonymous func');
            subForm.show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: irrAdd is the id of the button who's even i want to listen for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is probably submitting, do it like this

```
addBtn.on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('in anonymous func');
    subForm.show();
});
```

Note that the id `irrAdd` does not seem to exist in the markup, and that you could also change the buttons type to `button`

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery toggle(); function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var subForm = $("#MainContent_dynamicSubForm");
        var addBtn = $("#irrAdd");

        console.log("before hide");
        subForm.hide();
        console.log("after hide");
        addBtn.on("click", function () {
            console.log('in anonymous func');
            subForm.toggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah toggle() i tried that but in vain. anyway thanks for your response!